# Error in Universal Kriging using gstat package in R

Tags: r, kriging, geostatistical-analyst, gstat

I am trying to perform universal kriging in R using the gstat package and running into the following error:

```
krige(formula = CDD_LT_stC ~ Imperv1km + Elev_new, locations = sp.cal_data, newdata = sp.studygrid, model = modelfit, nmax = 200)

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Imperv1km' not found
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix this?

However, I was able to perform ordinary kriging with:

```
krige(formula = CDD_LT_stC ~ 1, locations = sp.cal_data, newdata = sp.studygrid, model = modelfit, nmax = 200)
```

Comment: What is in your `sp.cal_data` data frame? It is saying there is no column called `Imperv1km`. Hard for us to answer without more details or a copy of your data.

Comment: @Spacedman It's a `"SptatialPointsDataFrame"` and does include the column `Imperv1km` as well as the `Elev_new`. As I mentioned, the code worked if I use the ordinary kriging (i.e., `formula = CDD_LT_stC ~ 1`) but isn't working when I am using universal kriging (i.e., `formula = CDD_LT_stC ~ Imperv1km + Elev_new`). In both cases, the dataset are the same.

Comment: Edit your post to show some information about `sp.cal_data` - at a very minimum the output of `summary` on it.

Comment: And are you using the same `modelfit` object?

Comment: And do those columns exist in your `newdata`?

Comment: Thank you for your question which made me realize that the `newdata` should include those columns. For ordinary kriging, it is not required but it is required for the universal kriging. It ran smoothly once I fixed the `newdata`.